# ElasticSearch: count the occurance of value in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I have an index consider "INDEX-01" with the following field
'''

```
INDEX-01
 "IPS":[
    "1.2.3.4",
    "192.16.2.4",
    "192.16.2.3",
    "192.16.2.4"
]
```

'''
I have to count the number of occurance of a particular IP example consider "192.16.2.4"

Here is the mapping of the field:
'''

```
        "IPS": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        }
```

'''

I have tried using script but it is not working as expected, can someone please help what wrong I am doing or how can I acheive it. I cannot change the mapping.

'''

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "script": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "params._source.CALL_HOPS.stream().filter(value -> value == '192.16.2.4').count()"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: So you need to find documents where the same IP address `192.16.2.4` is contained twice in the `IPS.keyword` array? And if yes, what do you want to do next with those documents?

Comment: yes I need to find documents where the same IP address is contained twice, If I find any such document I would be triggering an sns event

Comment: How many documents do you have approximately?

Comment: there could be any number of documents it could be sometime more than 20,000